# Vue Class Component: How to custom options

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

Currently I use Vue 2 with Typescript, but I can't add options to the component

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue"; // @ is an alias to /src

@Component<Home>({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  middleware: "yyy",
})
export default class Home extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.middleware);
  }
}
</script>
```

I got undefined!

I found 1 problem similar to this, I tried but still no result

[Extend Component options](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/100)

My src\shims-vue.d.ts

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    middleware?: string;
  }
}

declare module "vue/types/options" {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    middleware?: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type declaration is missing an import for `Vue`:

```js
// shims-vue.d.ts
import Vue from 'vue' 

declare module "vue/types/options" {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    middleware?: string;
  }
}
```

To access the option from your component, use `this.$options.middleware` (not `this.middleware`):

```js
export default class Home extends Vue {
  mounted() {           
    console.log(this.$options.middleware);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's for instance properties. That same page shows how to augment component options with `vue/types/vue`.